# swift - Find duplicate dictionaries in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, foreach

I am looking to count the number of duplicate dictionaries inside an array/dictionary and return an array with the number of duplicate ID strings. Below is a sample of the array I have.

```
struct item {
   var id = [String:String]()
   var name = [String:String]()
   var price = [String:Int]()
}

array = [{ "id": "xxxx1", "name": "prodName1", "price": 15},
           "id": "xxxx2", "name": "prodName2", "price": 20}
           "id": "xxxx1", "name": "prodName1", "price": 15}]

var numbered = [item.id:Int]
array.forEach{ (items) in
    numbered[items] = numbered[items] ?? 0 + 1                     
}
```

I've tried following a foreach counter (with a struct) but I can't seem to get it set up properly. I'm looking to get a result like this:

```
result = ["xxxx1": 2, "xxxx2": 1]
```

Comment: `= [item.id:Int]` isn't valid because `item.id` isn't a valid type. Even if it were (support you have `= [String: Int]`, that still isn't valid, because `[String: Int]` is a type, not a value. It's shorthand for `Dictionary<String, Int>`. If you wanted a value of that type, you would need to call `.init()` on it, or more succintly, just `= [String: Int]()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first fix your structure declaration. Then create an array with your structure elements. This will make your life much easier. Then you can simply use reduce to count there occurrences:

```
struct Item {
   let id: String
   let name: String
   let price: Int
}
```

---

```
let array = [("xxxx1", "prodName1", 15),
             ("xxxx2", "prodName2", 20),
             ("xxxx1", "prodName1", 15)].map(Item.init)

let result = array.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.id, default: 0] += 1 }
result // ["xxxx2": 1, "xxxx1": 2]
```